# Many duplicate values when using postgres uuid_generate_v4

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, uuid

We added a UUID column to our 80 million row DB and the default gets generated using the postgres `uuid_generate_v4()` function.

We backfilled the uuid using this script:

```
current = 1
batch_size = 1000
last_id = 80000000

while current < last_id
  start_id = current
  end_id = current + batch_size
  puts "WORKING ON current: #{current}"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute <<-SQL.squish
    UPDATE table_name
    SET public_id = uuid_generate_v4()
    WHERE id BETWEEN '#{start_id}' and '#{end_id}' AND public_id IS NULL
  SQL
  current = end_id + 1
end
```

however, at the end of the script, we found that we had 135 duplicates, with some even having 3. How is this possible? Does the `uuid_generate_v4()` function generate dupes with such high probability?

Comment: might be worth checking https://linux.die.net/man/3/uuid_generate_random on your host

Comment: Suspect your random number source. See http://ralphbecket.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/birthday-paradox-and-guid-collisions.html

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you using?

According to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93902/is-postgress-uuid-generate-v4-securely-random the ossp extension uses /dev/urandom so it might not work as expected all the time. (I haven't checked the claim.)

Have you tried using `gen_random_uuid()` instead?

Comment: We are on heroku, which is ubuntu. our postgres db is on RDS

Comment: @MatthewBerman then I would ask AWS for help. Which PostgreSQL are you using? I cannot seem reproduce your problem on my RDS PostgreSQL (9.5.4).

Comment: we're using PostgreSQL 9.4.7 according to RDS

Comment: @MatthewBerman then I suggest that you upgrade to the latest minor update 9.4.14

Answer (score 0):

https://doxygen.postgresql.org/uuid-ossp_8c.html#a9effb407a94b4ecc119d9546cd102c94

```
#ifdef HAVE_UUID_E2FS
    uuid_t      uu;

    uuid_generate_random(uu);
```

so you can try checking your `/dev/urandom`, eg:

```
for i in $(seq 1 8000000); do uuidgen >>/tmp/u; done
-bash-4.2$ cat /tmp/u | sort | uniq -c | sort -r | head -3
      1 fffe894a-63e3-47e0-aea2-563f9652afd3
      1 fffbb781-61d5-4751-b4eb-e45a8ed684b7
      1 fffa7bff-ea37-46db-925b-d58f931512be
```

a little brutal, but if you see dupes here (left `1` will be more then one, you probably should use `uuid_generate_v1()` or other function that does not rely on 
`/dev/urandom` or uses some timestamp in addition, or look for some other solution...
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html